# How to create Polygon from Geo points in google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, polygon, geopoints

I have a table in bigquery which contain 11 geo points with their ids. I want to create a polygon from these points. I am using below query to create a polygon. but getting error `ST_MakePolygon failed: Invalid polygon loop: Edge 2 has duplicate vertex with edge 7`, what is the correct way to create a polygon?

**Query:**

`Select ST_MAKEPOLYGON(ST_MAKELINE(ARRAY_AGG(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(wkt_geom)))) as polygons from bd.wari_lockdown_area`

**Table bd.wari_lockdown_area:**

[wari_lockdown_area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3BXO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You can use [ST_CONVEXHULL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_convexhull) - as in below example

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT 
    ST_CONVEXHULL(ST_UNION_AGG(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(wkt_geom))) AS polygons  
FROM 
  `bd.wari_lockdown_area`
```

If to apply to sample data in your question - result is

[image]